# Partial mock of template methods with EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

I have a couple of classes following the "Template Method" pattern.  Abstract class A, and concrete extensions, B and C.  Like this:

```java
public abstract class A
{
  protected abstract String getData() throws SomeException;

  public void doWork() throws OtherException
  {
    try
    {
      // business logic ...
      String data = this.getData();
      // more business logic ...
    }
    catch(SomeException e)
    {
      log("...", e);
      throw new OtherException("...", e);
    }
  }
}

public Class B extends A
{
  protected String getData() throws SomeException
  {
    // complicated logic relying on lots of dependencies
  }
}

public Class C extends A
{
  protected String getData() throws SomeException
  {
    // different but equally complicated logic relying on lots of dependencies
  }
}
```

I want to write a test to verify when getData() throws SomeException that OtherException is thrown.  I really want to avoid mocking up all of the complicated dependencies that would be required to force getData() to throw.  I don't care how getData() throws, I just want it to throw.  So I think a partial mock is what I want.  This is what I have:

```java
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
....
@Test(expected = OtherException.class)
public void testSomethingOrAnother() throws Exception
{
    B target = createMockBuilder(B.class).addMockedMethod("getData").createMock();

    expect(target.getData()).andThrow(SomeException.class).once();

    replay(target)

    try
    {
        target.doWork(); // expect this to throw OtherException;
    }
    finally
    {
        verify(target);
    }
}
```

The test looks good to me, but when I run it I get this:

```java
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<OtherException> but was<java.lang.RuntimeException>
    ... deleted for brevity ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Ambiguous name: More than one method are named getData
    at org.easymock.internal.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:96)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockBuilder.addMockedMethod(MockBuilder.java:73)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockBuilder.addMockedMethods(MockBuilder.java:92)
    at com.mycompany.more.packages.BTest(BTest.java:83)
    ... deleted for brevity ...
    ... 16 more
```

To be clear: There is NOT an overload of the getData() method anywhere in the hierarchy.

Is EasyMock able to do what I'm trying to do here?  What am I missing?

relevant versions numbers:

- EasyMock 3.0
- JUnit 4.4
- Java 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be the use of the addMockedMethod(String).  Not sure why EasyMock is complaining about an ambiguous method name if there are no overloads.  But the following worked for me:

```
@Test
        public void testSomethingOrAnother() {
            B target = null;
            try {
                target = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(B.class).addMockedMethod(B.class.getDeclaredMethod("getData")).createMock();
                EasyMock.expect(target.getData()).andThrow(new SomeException());
                EasyMock.replay(target);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                fail(e.getMessage());
            } catch (SomeException e) {
                fail(e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                target.doWork();
                fail("doWork should have thrown an exception");
            } catch (OtherException e) {
                //pass
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to go down that route myself but your reflection-foo is better than mine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

With Easymock:3.2 you are able to specify types of the parameters of the method. Take a look `IMockBuilder#addMockedMethod(String methodName,Class<?>... parameterTypes)`
Thanks.